# protoc compiler not working with grpc plugin

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, grpc

So I'm trying to follow the tutorial at https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html#generating-client-and-server-code, but I'm having trouble compiling using the grpc plugin with the protoc compiler. I've setup my pom.xml properly with the plugin(I think), but the compiler doesn't generate the files that the guide needs(namely, RouteGuideGrpc.java).

I'm currently compiling the .proto using "mvn protobuf:compile"

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>maven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.14.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how to add the grpc plugin to the protobuf compiler? Did I not install the plugin properly?

btw: I'm a giant noob at using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You're configuration appears correct. However, `protobuf:compile` does not run any protoc plugins (which includes the gRPC plugin); that's what `protobuf:compile-custom` does.

So you simply need to run:

```
mvn protobuf:compile-custom
```

The output will be placed in the `target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

please check your storage is enough or not for the target file.